# How to parser xml in livecode

Tags: xml, api, livecode

```
             on mouseUp 

               loadPreferences   
             end mouseUp
            command loadPreferences

               local tTree
               put readPreferencesToXMLTree() into tTree
               if tTree is empty then
                  exit loadPreferences
               end if
               processPreferencesTree tTree
               revDeleteXMLTree tTree
            end loadPreferences

            private function readPreferencesToXMLTree


               set the itemDelimiter to slash
                     local tPreferencesFile
               put the URL"http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/blackbox/live/45" into tPreferencesFile

               local tPreferencesData, tResult
               put tPreferencesFile into tPreferencesData
               put the result into tResult

               if tResult is not empty then
                  answer error "Failed to read preferences file at location: " & tPreferencesFile
                  return empty
               end if
               local tTree
               put revCreateXMLTree(tPreferencesData, false, true, false) into tTree   
               if tTree is not an integer then
                  answer error "Failed to process preferences file with error: " & tTree
                  return empty
               end if
               return tTree
            end readPreferencesToXMLTree





                 private command processPreferencesTree pTree   
                  local tPosts
                  put revXMLChildNames(pTree, "ArrayOfLiveStatus/LiveStatus", return, "Location", true) into tPosts     
               local tListOfNames
               repeat for each line tName in tPosts
                  put revXMLNodeContents(pTree, "ArrayOfLiveStatus/LiveStatus" & tName) & return after tListOfNames
               end repeat
               delete the last char of tListOfNames   
               local tOutput
               put tListOfNames after tOutput
               set the text of field "NameList" to tOutput

            end processPreferencesTree
```

I am using Livecode software.I am accessing web api "http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/blackbox/live/45" which return a xml data.I want to parse  location node but I always get a error"xmlerr, can't find element".What I am doing wrong please help.

Comment: I've just answered this same question on the Programming LiveCode for the Real Beginner Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This server returns JSON by default. Before you make the request, you need to set the content type to application/xml:

```
set the httpHeaders to "Content-Type: application/xml"
```

Now the server will return XML and you should be able to retrieve the required nodes.

Comment: But if i click on that link i get xml Reponse data "http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/blackbox/live/45".

Comment: Yes, in your browser you get XML because your browser it smart enough to know that it wants XML. In LiveCode you get JSON. Just try it. If it doesn't work, then there is another problem as well, but it will definitely not work if you don't set the httpHeaders.

Comment: where i have to put these tag in set the httpHeaders to "Content-Type: application/xml" please reply